# WPF - Exceptions not caught?

Tags: wpf, exception

I'm trying to implement a login window, in WPF.

I have a MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ...
    Closing="Window_Closing">
    ...
```

And then in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
    loginWindow.Owner = this;
    loginWindow.ShowDialog();
    ...
```

In the LoginWindow constructor I'm throwing an exception. It's never caught.

If I wrap the contents of Window_Loaded in a try/catch block, I can catch the exception, but if I rethrow it, from within Window_Load(), it's never caught.

This seems very odd, to me.  I guess I'm used to environments where uncaught exceptions kill the app.  Is there something I need to do to enable this, in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this construct will restore the exception to visibility and allow you to catch it in the CurrentDomain_UnhandledException method on an x86 build...

```
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= MainWindow_Loaded;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, (SendOrPostCallback) delegate
        {
            Login l = new Login {Owner = this};
            l.ShowDialog();
        }, new object[] {null});
    }
```